# iOS Widget is crashing when cornerRadius or clipShape is applied in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, crash, widgetkit

My iOS Widget is crashing as soon I add the `cornerRadius` modifier to a view in my SwiftUI layout or a `clipShape` to clip a view.

Did anybody experience the same behaviour and found a solution?

I tried it with Xcode 12.1 and iOS 14.1 Simulator and also with Xcode 12.2 and iOS 14.2 Simulator which gave the same result.

Example code that's crashing the widget:

```
Image("sampleimage")
.background(Color.blue)
.cornerRadius(20)
```

Comment: I am also facing same type of issue

Comment: I have used cornerRadius at a lot of places in my widgets. I am not facing this issue. Can you be specific where are you facing that?

Comment: Same thing was happening to me but only for the "clipShape". I had to remove it for stability. Funny thing is that it only happened to me when reordering the views that used "clipShape".